# How do you use wget in repl.it bash?

Tags: bash, replit

I am trying to run a .deb using wget.

Here is my code:

```
wget https://debian.pkgs.org/11/virtualbox-amd64/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.32-149290~Debian~bullseye_amd64.deb.html
```

Whenever  I run the code I get this error:

```
main.sh: line 1: wget: command not found
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the virtualbox package in replit?

Comment: Install `wget` in a directory which is listed in variable `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `curl` in replit.

```
curl downloadurl -—output filename
```